# Adding a ceiling fan to circuit of light fixtures

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, junction-box

I have 4 recessed 40 watt lights in the ceiling of the living room. They are all on the same switch (circuit). Can I add a ceiling fan to the room and splice the conductor into one of the 4 J boxes so I won't have to run new wire?
Thanks
Matt

Comment: Are they currently on a dimmer?  Would you ever wish them to be?

Comment: they are, but don't have to be if it makes the fan install simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can do this because the standard fans draw only ~< 1 A of current. This is an easy way to install a fan but of course the lights must be on for the fan to be powered.

You could switch the fan off and change speeds with a remote controller. Receiver in the fan shroud and battery powered remote controller.

If you don't want to bother with a remote, you could control the fan with pull chain switch. I have had some trouble with the remote that came with the new Hunter fans. Or the problem may be with the fan itself. It won't run on high.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to be sure there is nothing other than the lights you mentioned on that circuit. Turn off the breaker running those lights and verify nothing else has lost power. If nothing else is on the circuit then yes you can add the ceiling fan without worrying about overloading the circuit. As another contributor mentioned your lights will have to be on in order for the fan to work, unless you run another wire back to the switch.

Comment: Another *cable* back to the switch (which has one more wire than the current cable).  You can't add single wires except in the rare instance when you are working in conduit, because the normal way of wiring conduit is single wires.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.